# Ardour segmentation fault

Tags: kubuntu, ardour

I can't get Ardour to run. This is the terminal output. I'm running Kubuntu 20.04.

```
~$ ardour
Ardour6.5.0~ds0 (built using 6.5.0~ds0-1~ubuntu20.04.1~ppa1 and GCC version 9.3.0)
Ardour: [INFO]: Your system is configured to limit Ardour to 1048576 open files
Ardour: [INFO]: Loading system configuration file /etc/ardour6/system_config
Ardour: [INFO]: CPU vendor: GenuineIntel
Ardour: [INFO]: AVX-capable processor
Ardour: [INFO]: CPU brand: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
Ardour: [INFO]: Using AVX optimized routines
Ardour: [INFO]: Loading plugin meta data file /usr/share/ardour6/plugin_metadata/plugin_tags
Ardour: [INFO]: Loading default ui configuration file /etc/ardour6/default_ui_config
Ardour: [INFO]: Loading 449 MIDI patches from /usr/share/ardour6/patchfiles
Ardour: [INFO]: Loading color file /usr/share/ardour6/themes/dark-ardour.colors
Ardour: [INFO]: Loading ui configuration file /etc/ardour6/clearlooks.rc
Ardour: [INFO]: Loading bindings from /etc/ardour6/ardour.keys
Loading ui configuration file /etc/ardour6/clearlooks.rc
set default folder to /home/caleb
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

---

This is the output when ran as root if that has any clues:

```
sudo ardour
[sudo] password for caleb: 
Ardour6.5.0~ds0 (built using 6.5.0~ds0-1~ubuntu20.04.1~ppa1 and GCC version 9.3.0)
Ardour: [INFO]: Your system is configured to limit Ardour to 1048576 open files
Ardour: [INFO]: Loading system configuration file /etc/ardour6/system_config
Ardour: [INFO]: Loading user configuration file /root/.config/ardour6/config
Ardour: [INFO]: CPU vendor: GenuineIntel
Ardour: [INFO]: AVX-capable processor
Ardour: [INFO]: CPU brand: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
Ardour: [INFO]: Using AVX optimized routines
Ardour: [INFO]: Loading plugin meta data file /usr/share/ardour6/plugin_metadata/plugin_tags
Ardour: [INFO]: Loading plugin statistics file /root/.config/ardour6/plugin_metadata/plugin_stats
Ardour: [INFO]: Loading default ui configuration file /etc/ardour6/default_ui_config
Ardour: [INFO]: Loading user ui configuration file /root/.config/ardour6/ui_config
Ardour: [INFO]: Loading 449 MIDI patches from /usr/share/ardour6/patchfiles
Ardour: [INFO]: Loading color file /usr/share/ardour6/themes/dark-ardour.colors
Ardour: [INFO]: Loading ui configuration file /etc/ardour6/clearlooks.rc
Ardour: [INFO]: Loading bindings from /etc/ardour6/ardour.keys
Loading ui configuration file /etc/ardour6/clearlooks.rc
Found nothing along /root/.config/ardour6/templates:/usr/share/ardour6/templates
```

```
$ apt-cache policy ardour
ardour:   
Installed: 1:6.5.0+ds0-1~ubuntu20.04.1~ppa1   
Candidate: 1:6.5.0+ds0-1~ubuntu20.04.1~ppa1   
Version table:
  *** 1:6.5.0+ds0-1~ubuntu20.04.1~ppa1 500         
500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntustudio-ppa/ardour-backports/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages         
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status      
1:5.12.0-3ubuntu4 500         
500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: An additional finding: Ardour will run if I use sudo.

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy ardour` ?

Comment: `ardour:
 Installed: 1:6.5.0+ds0-1~ubuntu20.04.1~ppa1
  Candidate: 1:6.5.0+ds0-1~ubuntu20.04.1~ppa1
  Version table:
 *** 1:6.5.0+ds0-1~ubuntu20.04.1~ppa1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntustudio-ppa/ardour-backports/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:5.12.0-3ubuntu4 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages`

Comment: Did you try some options like `--disable-plugins` (safe mode) or `--no-hw-optimizations`?

Answer (score 0):

The `sudo` maybe a clue. Possibly you have wrong permissions for Ardour configuration folders.

To fix the permissions use command below:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.config/ardour6 ~/.config/ardour5
```

and then restart Ardour.

Also make sure that you have followed The Ardour Manual, especially [Ubuntu Linux setup page](https://manual.ardour.org/setting-up-your-system/platform-specifics/ubuntu-linux/):

```
sudo usermod -a -G audio $USER
```

Comment: I assume `$USER` I should replace with my username or type as-is?

Comment: Use it as written, it is variable. It will be substituted with your actual username by shell.

Comment: [`$USER` will be replaced automatically](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-set-and-list-environment-variables-on-linux#h1-list-environment-variables) (run `echo $USER`)

Comment: This did not fix it.

Comment: Please reboot and try again.Then try good idea which was recommended by @PabloBianchi - "Did you try some options like `--disable-plugins` (safe mode) or `--no-hw-optimizations`? "

Comment: Rebooted and tried the options. Still no luck.

Comment: I'm not Ardour expert, but did you tried to use JACK or PulseAudio at launch dialog?

Comment: When it runs as root, I used PulseAudio. I don't have JACK installed. When I run as normal user, I never get to the launch dialog.

Comment: Scratch that. I used ALSA. It wouldn't connect to Pulse.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer through the Ardour IRC. It turns out, Ardour conflicts with the global menu applet in Latte dock.

The solution is to add
`export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=""` to the ardour script in /usr/bin.

That forces Ardour to ignore the global menu and run properly.